# How to read a parameter from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

please help me for read a parameter from array in php:
when use from print_r for view array , result is:

```
getUserServicesResponse Object ( 
[getUserServiceResponse] => 
[return] => stdClass Object ( 
    [isactive] => 1 
    [lastQnum] => 0 
    [qnum] => 5 
    [score] => 0 
    [service] => stdClass Object ( 
        [countActive] => 73657 
        [countAll] => 199784 
        [lastTime] => 2015-12-01T08:38:06.065+03:30 
        [maxScore] => 33000 
        [minScore] => 0 
        [minregdate] => 2014-08-05T15:27:12+04:30 
        [serviceName] => game 
        [topNumber] => 09121153321 
    ) 
    [serviceID] => 12946 
    )
)
```

i want print serviceName value from  array that is game or print score from array that is 0
thanks

Comment: it's very hard to tell what's going on there. Can you format the output? Put a <pre> tag in front of the print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a parameter from **php object (stdClass or normal)**

you need `object name` with `->` and the `attribute name` which you want to access,

in your case there are many **stdClass objects** one after another so the correct ways is,

```
 echo $getUserServicesResponse->return->service->serviceName;
```

> **output:**

```
game
```

**FYI**

the structure for which i have generated the output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [isactive] => Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
            [service] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [serviceName] => game
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$object->getUserServiceResponse->service->serviceName;
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer which make it useful for OP and  others

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.